# How can you pin a group of vertices so they don't move during animation?

Tags: animation, vertex-groups

I have an object that I want to animate by scaling it along the z-axis. I want one opening to be pinned in such a way that it doesn't move.

This is not related to cloth physics in any way.

The following is a picture of the object, I want to pin the selected vertices during animation.
Thanks for any help.

If my Blender version has anything to do with my issue, it is 2.83

[image]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html

Comment: as Batfinger says you could hook, you could also use shapekeys, or a one that would control everything except your vertices...

Comment: Thanks for your help, now they aren't moving.